# MySQL - get min and max values for id's in group

Tags: mysql, join, self

Updated:

TABLE: mydata

```
    id    trans_id  CURRENT   CUST_DATE   
    ------------------------------------
    16    2362      152.40    2015-05-11
    16    2363      146.80    2015-05-26
    16    1669      147.00    2015-06-16
    16    1979      148.60    2015-07-06
    16    2344      144.00    2015-08-06
    104   1280      161.40    2015-05-29
    104   1553      158.20    2015-06-10
    104   1898      158.20    2015-06-29
    104   2131      158.20    2015-07-15
    104   2223      158.20    2015-07-27
    104   2294      158.20    2015-08-03
```

I need a query that will return the first and last value for CURRENT within each group of ID's based on CUST_DATE.

Couple of items to point out:

1. I'm only showing two ID's in this example. The real table has thousands of distinct ID's.
2. trans_id is an auto incremented field. My initial query had max(trans_id) and min(trans_id)...which worked until a new row was added with an earlier date value and caused the natural ascending order to become out-of-wack. You can see this issue on ID 16 in the table above.

I've been noodling with this seemingly simple query for two days now...just can't wrap my head around it.

Expected output (flat structure):

```
    id    CURRENT_MAX  CURRENT_MIN   
    -------------------------------
    16    152.40       144.00
    104   161.40       158.20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d76b/11)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE mydata
    (`id` int, `trans_id` int, `CURRENT` double, `CUST_DATE` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO mydata
    (`id`, `trans_id`, `CURRENT`, `CUST_DATE`)
VALUES
    (16, 2362, 152.40, '2015-05-11 00:00:00'),
    (16, 2363, 146.80, '2015-05-26 00:00:00'),
    (16, 1669, 147.00, '2015-06-16 00:00:00'),
    (16, 1979, 148.60, '2015-07-06 00:00:00'),
    (16, 2344, 144.00, '2015-08-06 00:00:00'),
    (104, 1280, 161.40, '2015-05-29 00:00:00'),
    (104, 1553, 158.20, '2015-06-10 00:00:00'),
    (104, 1898, 158.20, '2015-06-29 00:00:00'),
    (104, 2131, 158.20, '2015-07-15 00:00:00'),
    (104, 2223, 158.20, '2015-07-27 00:00:00'),
    (104, 2294, 158.20, '2015-08-03 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id, MIN(CURRENT), MAX(CURRENT) 
FROM mydata
GROUP BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d76b/11/0)**:

```
|  id | MIN(CURRENT) | MAX(CURRENT) |
|-----|--------------|--------------|
|  16 |          144 |        152.4 |
| 104 |        158.2 |        161.4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Several rows share the same minimum current, so I assume you want all of them as you've not specified otherwise...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id    INT NOT NULL
 , trans_id  INT NOT NULL 
 ,CURRENT   DECIMAL(5,2)
 ,CUST_DATE   DATE NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (16   ,2362      ,152.40    ,'2015-05-11'),
 (16   ,2363      ,146.80    ,'2015-05-26'),
 (16   ,1669      ,147.00    ,'2015-06-16'),
 (16   ,1979      ,148.60    ,'2015-07-06'),
 (16   ,2344      ,144.00    ,'2015-08-06'),
 (104  ,1280      ,161.40    ,'2015-05-29'),
 (104  ,1553      ,158.20    ,'2015-06-10'),
 (104  ,1898      ,158.20    ,'2015-06-29'),
 (104  ,2131      ,158.20    ,'2015-07-15'),
 (104  ,2223      ,158.20    ,'2015-07-27'),
 (104  ,2294      ,158.20    ,'2015-08-03');

SELECT a.*
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN
     (
       SELECT id, MAX(current) x_current FROM my_table GROUP BY id
       UNION
       SELECT id, MIN(current) x_current FROM my_table GROUP BY id
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id AND b.x_current = a.current;
  +-----+----------+---------+------------+
  | id  | trans_id | CURRENT | CUST_DATE  |
  +-----+----------+---------+------------+
  |  16 |     2362 |  152.40 | 2015-05-11 |
  |  16 |     2344 |  144.00 | 2015-08-06 |
  | 104 |     1280 |  161.40 | 2015-05-29 |
  | 104 |     1553 |  158.20 | 2015-06-10 |
  | 104 |     1898 |  158.20 | 2015-06-29 |
  | 104 |     2131 |  158.20 | 2015-07-15 |
  | 104 |     2223 |  158.20 | 2015-07-27 |
  | 104 |     2294 |  158.20 | 2015-08-03 |
  +-----+----------+---------+------------+
```

or

```
 SELECT a.*
   FROM my_table a
   JOIN
      (
        SELECT id
             , MAX(current) max_current
             , MIN(current) min_current 
          FROM my_table 
         GROUP  
            BY id
      ) b
     ON b.id = a.id AND a.current IN (b.max_current,b.min_current);
```

Since this question was first asked, the specification has changed significantly. The new requirement is too obvious to bother with.

Comment: Strawberry, i apologize for changing the specs on you guys.  Thanks for the feedback. I'll try asking it again in a few days.